# TargetInvocationException

Tags: c#-4.0

I wrote the code below:

```
private void DisplayStartUps()
{
    Form2 dialog = new Form2();

    if (dialog.ShowDialog(this) == DialogResult.OK)
    {
        // Read the contents of testDialog's TextBox.
        totalTeams = dialog.NumOfTeams;
    }
    dialog.Dispose();
}
```

When the form 2 opens, then I click on the "red x" pn the top to close the form. I got the message:

> TargetInvocationException was unhandled

What does that mean and how to fix it?

Comment: Can you show us the code inside under Form2.Closed, Form2.Closing events if any? Also is there anything running on a different thread?

Comment: What happens when dialog.Dispose() is not called?

Comment: This is the code under Form2:public partial class Form2 : Form
    {
        private int numOfTeams;
        public Form2()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }    
        
        public int NumOfTeams { 
            get
            {
                return numOfTeams;
            }
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
         
             this.numOfTeams = (int)numericUpDown1.Value;
        }



    }

Comment: When dialog.Dispose() is not called. I got the same result

Comment: The initialization part is ok. Do you have something running in the background thread? Or something working with reflection? We would need more code from form2 to help.. Mainly show us the code under main button event, and also if any under form close..